# mysql insert statement in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I want to show a list in `PHP` with the entries in a `mysql-database`. it works, now in the same `.php` file, a form should insert a new entry in the database, and it should be then shown in the list. My attempts have failed, where the last entry is always inserted in the database upon every access to the site. Below is my code:

PHP-Part adminlist.php:

```
$adminname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['adminname']);
    $server = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['server']);

if(!empty($adminname && $server))
{
    $insert =  "INSERT INTO admins (ID, Name, Passwort, Server, Anmeldungen) VALUES (NULL, '" . $adminname . "', '', '" . $server . "', '0')";
    $insertquery = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
}
```

HTML-Part adminlist.php:

```
<form name='einfuegen' action='adminlist.php' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Server</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name='adminname' value='' /></td>
                    <td><input name='server' value='' /></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Einf&uuml;gen' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

I've tried also to set under the form

```
$server = 0;
$adminname = 0;
```

and edited the above:

```
if(!empty($adminname && $server) && ($server != 0) && ($adminname != 0))
```

In this case it won't work and nothing is inserted. How could I set only one to be inserted and be shown then in the list?

Comment: just reload your page after inserting data

Comment: Please use `if(!empty($adminname) && !empty($server))` instead of `if(!empty($adminname && $server))`

Comment: @mapek better yet, just use `if($adminname && $server)`, as both of those variables are already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this `if(!empty($adminname && $server))` with `if(!empty($adminname) && !empty($server))` And, don't unnecessary concatenate values for inserting.

**Edited Code**

```
if(!empty($adminname) && !empty($server))
{
    $insert =  "INSERT INTO admins (ID, Name, Passwort, Server, Anmeldungen) VALUES (NULL, '$adminname','', '$server', '0')";
    $insertquery = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
}
```

**For OP :**

Use `header("location:adminlist.php");` for redirecting it after submitting.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

if($_POST['submitValue']) {

    $adminname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['adminname']);
    $server = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['server']);

    $insert =  "INSERT INTO admins (ID, Name, Passwort, Server, Anmeldungen) VALUES (NULL, '$adminname','', '$server', '0')";
    $insertquery = mysqli_query($con, $insert);

    header("location:adminlist.php");

}?>



<form name='einfuegen' action='' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Server</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name='adminname' value='' /></td>
            <td><input name='server' value='' /></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='submitValue' value='Einf&uuml;gen' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: BTW your profile is the funniest one I ever seen on SOF. No serious business at all. LOL!

Comment: Thanku @AnandG Jee. `Be Funny. Go Sunny`

Comment: So I do not need the "   $server = 0; $adminname = 0;" at he bottom?

Comment: No. No. It's Not Like That. Why Unnecessary concatenating `'" . $adminname . "'`. It's not an error. Just for better way to write code. I feel easy this way only @JohnHSmith

Comment: But how can I delete the last given words in form after refreshing the page?

Comment: I'm not getting what you are asking. Please explain briefly what problem you are facing @JohnHSmith

Comment: If I enter the two things in the form, push the submit button and refresh the site, it works. But if I then push the submit button again without entering something in the form, the last entry from before is inserted in the database again. This is the problem @NanaPartykar

Comment: Ok. Ok. I got it. You are inserting and viewing data in same page. means in **adminlist.php** page ? @JohnHSmith

Comment: Ok Wait for 5-10 min. I will be back @JohnHSmith

Comment: Hey @JohnHSmith : Why not to use 2 pages. Like for submitting another page (where inserting will be done.) and in one page `<form></form>` and view can be done.

Comment: Because its easier for me to interact with this database in one page.

Comment: My suggestion. Do in 2 page. If you want i can help you. It's easy @JohnHSmith

Comment: This is the easy way, this is easy for me, too. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Wait @JohnHSmith : I got it. use header('location:adminlist.php'); after insert. Use my code same to same. It will work.

Comment: I will try it when I'm at home again.

Comment: Sure. And, let me know. As i'm also curious to know @JohnHSmith

Comment: Got it. But you've got an error in the line with $adminname = ... it must be [...]escape_string(<CONNECTION NAME>, $_POST[...]@NanaPartykar

Comment: Yeah. It may be. As i was checking in my localhost. Typo mistake. If you think this answer helped you, please tick it as correct answer, as it will other user to find it easily. Thanks @JohnHSmith